# Python: PCA + k-means not working

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means, pca

I have a set of abundances as a function of time for a list of molecules. To begin with I am starting with a small sample of 99 time steps and 20 molecules, but I will want to expand this much further later on to a few hundred molecules.

Because the abundances can be quite irregular at times with time, I want to reduce the data using `Principal Component Analysis` and then conduct a  `kmeans` analysis in order to group molecules into clusters based on the behaviour as a function of time.

I found [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_digits.html) which seems to do what I want to using the `sklearn` library, but I am having problems getting it to work on my `data` as I am getting the error `ValueError: Incorrect number of features. Got 2 features, expected 10`.

If I change `n_components=2` and `n_clusters=2` the code runs and produces the following;

[image: Resulting plot without data]

However, this doesn't plot the data, just the different clusters areas and the centroids of the clusters, and I have no idea why that is.

Basically I have two problems:

- I can only run the code with `n_components=2` and `n_clusters=2` but I want to try different values here to get the best match.
- The resulting plot does not include the data, only clusters areas and centroids.

Here is the code:

```
reduced_data = PCA(n_components=10).fit_transform(data)
kmeans = KMeans(init='k-means++', n_clusters=10, n_init=10)
kmeans.fit(reduced_data)

# Step size of the mesh. Decrease to increase the quality of the VQ.
h = .02     # point in the mesh [x_min, m_max]x[y_min, y_max].

# Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color to each
x_min, x_max = reduced_data[:, 0].min() - 1, reduced_data[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = reduced_data[:, 1].min() - 1, reduced_data[:, 1].max() + 1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))

# Obtain labels for each point in mesh. Use last trained model.
Z = kmeans.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

# Put the result into a color plot
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
plt.clf()
plt.imshow(Z, interpolation='nearest',
           extent=(xx.min(), xx.max(), yy.min(), yy.max()),
           cmap=plt.cm.Paired,
           aspect='auto', origin='lower')

centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1],marker='x', s=169, linewidths=3,color='w', zorder=10)
plt.xlim(x_min, x_max)
plt.ylim(y_min, y_max)
plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())
plt.savefig('PCAclustering_'+ run_label + time_label +'.pdf')
plt.close()
```

Comment: I don't think that it's possible to draw 10 dimensional points on 2 dimensional plane :) It makes no sense to set n_components with value bigger than 2 in your case (Because you want to draw them on plane).

Also, where ValueError occurs exactly? Maybe you are passing 2 dimensional dataset and trying to project it onto 10 principal components?

Comment: Ok, that might mean I misunderstood things. I have understood it as `n_components` for `RCA` is basically determining the level of accuracy you want to "fit the data", so how many components you want. 
`n_clusters` I understand is the number of clusters you want to split your data into? So basically how many groups should your data be split into. 
Is that correct?

The error occurs on the line `Z = kmeans.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])`

Comment: n_components for PCA determines number of principal components on which transform (or fit_transform) method will project your samples. So if you have 20 features for each sample in dataset - after transformation your dataset will have only 10 features. 10 features = 10 columns in matrix.